flutter circular image doesn't fit in circular container
I'm using circular images inside circular containers, but there always seems to be some space left in the container.
I've tried using ClipOval, CircleAvatar to clip the image and experimented with BoxFit.cover and BoxFit.fill. I also adjusted the width and height of the containers, but I still notice gaps, especially in certain aspect ratios. How can I ensure that the image fits perfectly within the circular container without leaving any space?
And also, when I use Image.asset directly with the same width and height for the container, the image still appears smaller than the container.
Column(
  children: [
    Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        color: Colors.red,
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage('assets/10.png'),
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
        ),
      ),
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
    ),
    Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      child: Image.asset(
        'assets/10.png',
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),  
    ),
  ],
)



Thank you

post your "assets/10.png"` image too, i bet it contains some padding

this is what i thought: your round image does not fit the image bounds completely, it has some padding - remove it

I hadn't thought that a transparent background could be part of the image itself. I’ll try modifying the image first. Thank you!

@Christy_Vicky The image you've provided already have freespace outside the shape. Maybe thats the reason why you are finding gaps. When i tried, The first Container works pretty  well . You may try it with Container(             decoration: BoxDecoration(                 shape: BoxShape.circle,                 color: Colors.red,                 image: DecorationImage(                     image: NetworkImage('https://picsum.photos/300/100'),                      fit: BoxFit.cover,                 ),             ),             width: 100,             height: 100, )

Simply wrap it with ClipRRect() widget and then provide the radius and require parameters.
Your Issue will be resolved.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Looking at your image, it already has transparent empty space in the image itself, try crop that space in any image editor tool.

Yes, I did. Thank you!
